# extracting one variable from multi-run file

Tags: r, simulation

From a simulation I accumulated data in a separate file for each run, in the format below:

```
timestep, ni, n.SL, n.IL
0, 0, 0, 0
1, 4, 2, 3
2, 5, 3, 3
3, 5, 5, 4
```

Later I extracted (using loops) to intermediate dataframes, one for each tracked variable, e.g. for n.SL in this format:

timestep, run1, run2, run3, …, mean, max, min
0, 5, 3, 4..., mean of run columns, max, min
1, 4, 7, 4..., mean of run columns, max, min
2, 8, 5, 4..., mean of run columns, max, min
3, 7, 1, 4..., mean of run columns, max, min

And then I plotted using mean, max and min for geom_ribbon, like this:
[image: example of plot produced]

Now my problem is I want to store multiple runs (of same parameter set) in one file instead of a separate file for each run. The start of each run is when timestep resets to 0.

```
timestep, ni, n.SL, n.IL
0, 0, 0, 0
1, 4, 2, 3
2, 5, 3, 3
3, 5, 5, 4
0, 0, 0, 0
1, 4, 1, 2
2, 5, 3, 2
3, 5, 3, 4
```

My question is that I am unsure of a good R-friendly way to create the intermediate dataframes (a column for each run) from this multirun file, given that for different parameter settings the number of timesteps will vary between files (though not between runs within a file as they have to be same length for mean/max/min). For example another file might have 5 timesteps like this:

```
timestep, ni, n.SL, n.IL
0, 0, 0, 0
1, 4, 2, 3
2, 5, 3, 3
3, 5, 5, 4
4, 3, 4, 2
5, 1, 2, 2
0, 0, 0, 0
1, 4, 1, 2
2, 5, 3, 2
3, 5, 3, 4
4, 3, 1, 2
5, 0, 0, 1
```

Thanks for reading. Any suggestion would be gratefully received.

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: Thanks for asking. The intermediate dataframe would look like this:<br> timestep, run1, run2, …., mean, max, min<br> 0, 2, 3, 4..., 3, 4, 2<br>1, 2, 3, 4..., 3, 4, 2<br>2, 2, 3, 4..., 3, 4, 2<br><br>3, 2, 3, 4..., 3, 4, 2<br> In other words, a column for each run.

Comment: can you include that in your question.. Edit the question with the expected output in it. In that case it will be faster for someone to see it

Comment: OK, I have edited to add that.

Comment: What is the logic of getting 0,2,3,4,...3,4,2??

Comment: your question is completely unclear. Please revise!

Comment: I have revised to show last three columns are mean, max, and min of the output data in other columns. First column is timestep number, the numbers in other columns could be anything, I just put some placeholding numbers in.